# python re string replace function with less match

Tags: python, regex

I use Python's `re` module to replace a substring, such as:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r"a.*b","ab","acbacbacb")
'ab'
```

This matches `.*` with `cbacbac`, but I want it to match `c` three times, so that the output is `ababab`.

Could anybody tell me how to do it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [python regex first/shortest match](/q/11301387/90527)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regex by default is greedy. Use `.*?`

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r"a.*?b","ab","acbacbacb")
'ababab'
>>>
```

http://docs.python.org/library/re.html

> The `*`, `+`, and `?` qualifiers are all greedy; they match as much
>   text as possible. Sometimes this behaviour isn’t desired; if the RE
>   `<.*>` is matched against `'<H1>title</H1>'`, it will match the entire
>   string, and not just `'<H1>'`. Adding `?` after the qualifier makes it
>   perform the match in non-greedy or minimal fashion; as few characters
>   as possible will be matched. Using `.*?` in the previous expression will
>   match only `'<H1>'`.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest solution would be to use the lazy (non-greedy) `*?` operator:

```
>>> re.sub(r"a.*?b","ab","acbacbacb")
'ababab'
```

This might however have an impact on performance. Because of the structure of this regex, you can just as well use the equivalent

```
re.sub(r"a[^b]*b","ab","acbacbacb")
```

which could perform better, depending on how good the optimizer is.

If you have even more a priori knowledge about the structure of the `.*` part, you should make it even more explicit. Say, for example, that you already know that between the `a` and the `b` there will be only `c`'s, you can do

```
re.sub(r"ac*b","ab","acbacbacb")
```

Answer (score 0):

use non-greedy match:

```
re.sub(r"a.*?b","ab","acbacbacb")
'ababab'
```

from http://docs.python.org/library/re.html:

> The '*', '+', and '?' qualifiers are all greedy; they match as much
>   text as possible. Sometimes this behaviour isn’t desired. [...] Adding
>   '?' after the qualifier makes it perform the match in non-greedy or
>   minimal fashion; as few characters as possible will be matched.

Answer (score 0):

```
re.sub(r"a.b","ab","acbacbacb")
'ababab'
```

Comment: This will not match `accb`, for example. How can you know that this is intended?

Comment: Yes.. it doesn't work for accb. The above one works only for single character replacement.